# Image multiple objects are present how to put views on it

Tags: java, android

[see attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMCbj.jpg)

Should i use multiple layouts instead of weights for executing this scenario.

Scenario is:
I've a kitchen image and it has objects 77 total. Kitchen image further divided into 2 parts left and right. As I've many objects I'm using single relative layout to manage them all at left and right side image.
So my question here is that to make them pixel perfect should I use weights or different layout like normal, large, x-large, landscape, etc.

I'm waiting for your opinions.

Comment: you may go to with `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: kindly see attached file as objects are part of the image they are not separate and I'm using <View> tag to put listeners on it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? you want these 77 objects to be clickable?

Comment: I've done the clickable part. using simple transparent View.

Comment: I've done the clickable part. using simple transparent View tag on each object. Right now problem is when i run on samsung j7 and hawaii honor 4x the views are scattered. as these phone have screen density xhdpi and screen size 5.5 and resolution 720 * 1268. I've made different layout folders layout-xhdpi layout-xxhdpi layout-xxxhdpi etc. but how to make the layout for these mobile screens. I've waiting for your reply. I'm managing densities but how to manage large screens with low density that is my question.

Comment: Maybe you can try using a SVG file as they would scale on different screen densities

Comment: please first see attached file svg file is not going to work on it.\